# SSRS - Adding total row + percentage of the total

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have two types of fruits - bananas and apples. My report shows (using matrix) how many of each type certain people have, using this test query:

```
SELECT 1 AS fruits, 1 AS bananas, 0 AS apples, 'person_1' AS people UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS fruits, 0 AS bananas, 1 AS apples, 'person_2' AS people
```

I want to remove the "fruits" field and add automatic calculation of the total of the two types on the row above. Also, add the % of the total for each fruit type, i.e. how big part of the total amount of bananas each person has.

[image]

I suspect this is done somehow by grouping the rows but I cant figure out which groups I need to use on rows. I don't have an obvious group by column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the data usually comes in a format like this:

```
SELECT 'person_1' AS people, 'bananas' AS FruitType, 1 AS FruitCount
UNION ALL
SELECT 'person_2' AS people, 'apples' AS FruitType, 1 AS FruitCount
```

[image: FruitAndPeople]

Using a Dataset like this, build a report with a matrix that shows FruitTypes in rows, people in columns and FruitCount (the sum of it) as data. This will automatically create a *FruitType* row group and a *people* column group:

[image: Basic Matrix]

Right-click both groups under *Row Groups* and *Column Groups* to add a total to each. For the FruitType group select **Add Total Before** and for the people group select **Add Total After**:

[image: Matrix with Totals]

Rename the cells I selected in the last screenshot to **TotalByPerson** (the total in the [people] column) and **TotalByFruitType** (the total in the [FruitType] row). Also, rename the total in the Total row and Total column to **GrandTotal**. This will make formulas for percentages more readable.

Now, to add a row for the percentage, right click on the row selector of the [FruitType] row to insert a row inside the group below the selected row:

[image: Adding the Percentage Row]

You can split the merged cells to enter a separated title for the percentage row, for example **[FruitType] %**:

[image: Percentage Row Title]

Now, there are just two formulas missing that you can define in the respective *Expression* window:

- in the [people] column: `=ReportItems!FruitCount.Value/ReportItems!TotalByPerson.Value`
- in the Total column : `=ReportItems!TotalByFruitType.Value/ReportItems!GrandTotal.Value`

Format both values as a percentage using the *Text Box Properties* window. After defining the background colors of the rows as desired, your design window should look like this:

[image: Designer of Final Report]

Running the report, you will receive the following result from the test data above:

[image]

Comment: Made it work with my dataset after some modifications, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

set up your matrix as per this image below:
[image]

detailed below design view showing grouping by row/columns:
[image]

results should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately the structure of the report must be very specific, exactly how it looks on my picture :(